# Как вырезать из строки первые вхождения букв и поместить их в массив?

Tags: python

Дается случайная строка. Например: `abrakadabra`.
Нужно из нее вырезать все первые вхождения букв и закинуть их в массив, при этом удалив из строки.

т.е. массив будет `abdkr`,
а строка будет `aaabra`

Как это можно реализовать?

Я предполагаю, что это регулярки. Я прав?

Comment: Для начала попробуйте обычный цикл по буквам строки. И удалить из строки ничего нельзя, поэтому на выходе у вас будет два массива: с первыми вхождениями букв и с остальными буквами. Потом из обоих массивов можно обратно строки будет сделать. Проверка наличия элемента в массиве или строке делается с помощью оператора `in`. Больше вам ничего не нужно.

Comment: Ну можно сразу получить первый массив - `uniq = "".join(dict.fromkeys(stroka))`. А дальше в цикле уже по этому массиву поудалять буквы по индексу.

Answer (score 0):

```
s = input()
chars_vector = []

for i in range(len(s)):
    if i == s.find(s[i]):
        chars_vector.append(i)

ls_s = [i for i in s]

for i in chars_vector:
    ls_s[i] = ''

for i in chars_vector:
    chars_vector[chars_vector.index(i)] = s[i]

print(''.join(ls_s), chars_vector)
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Это не лучше решение, но оно работает )))))
Выше дан хороший вариант со словарем))
Удачи!

Answer (score 0):

```
# Дана строка. Сохранить в ней только первые вхождения символов, удалив все остальное.
# Результат вывести в виде кортежа.
stroka = "abrakadabra"
print("Нашe предложение: ", stroka)  # выводим исходный результат
# Разделим нашу строку на отдельные символы:
a1 = []  # создаем пустой список, в котором будут уникальные элементы
# проверим нашу строку на дубляж символов
for spisok1 in stroka: # прогон букв по индексу из строки
    a1.append(spisok1) # добавляем поочередно элементы списка
    k1 = a1.count(spisok1) # создаем переменную для поиска дубляжа
    if k1 == 2: # создаем условие, при нахождении дубляжа
        print("удаляем дубляж:   ", a1.pop()) # сообщаем какой элемент повторился и удаляем его
print("полученный кортеж", tuple(a1)) # Результат выводим в виде кортежа
```